# ListView displaying list item twice

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-loadermanager

I am new to Android. I am developing a Notepad application.The NoteList displays every list item twice. I don't know why is showing that.I think it has something with onLoadFinished method, but I'm not sure.Here's my code :

**NoteList.java **

```
public class NoteList extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks < Cursor > {

private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT = 1;

private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private ArrayList < NoteItem > notes;
private NoteClassAdapter aa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notelist);
    notes = new ArrayList < NoteItem > ();
    int resID = R.layout.notes_row;
    aa = new NoteClassAdapter(this, resID, notes);
    setListAdapter(aa);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    //registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    Button addnote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addnotebutton);
    addnote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createNote();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("mode", "add");
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    long row_id = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("mode", "update");
    bundle.putLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, row_id);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    //  i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case DELETE_ID:
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        // mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(NotesDbAdapter.CONTENT_URI + "/" + info.id);
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Starts a new or restarts an existing Loader in this manager
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
}

// This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.
@Override
public Loader < Cursor > onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
        NotesDbAdapter.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader < Cursor > loader, Cursor cursor) {

    // dataAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    int keyTaskIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
    notes.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        NoteItem newItem = new NoteItem(cursor.getString(keyTaskIndex));

        notes.add(newItem);
    }
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader < Cursor > loader) {
    // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
    // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
    // longer using it.
    //  dataAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

}
```

**NoteClassAdapter.java**

```
    public class NoteClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < NoteItem > {

    int resource;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        TextView date;
    }

    public NoteClassAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList < NoteItem > items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @
    Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewholder;
        NoteItem item = getItem(position);

        String taskString = item.getTask();
        Date createdDate = item.getCreated();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        String dateString = sdf.format(createdDate);

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewholder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_row, null);
            viewholder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            viewholder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
        } else {
            viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewholder.date.setText(taskString);
        viewholder.text.setText(dateString);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

NoteItem.java

```
public class NoteItem {

 String task;
  Date created;

  public String getTask() {
    return task;
  }

  public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
  }

  public NoteItem(String _task) {
    this(_task, new Date(java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()));
  }

  public NoteItem(String _task, Date _created) {
    task = _task;
    created = _created;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    String dateString = sdf.format(created); 
    return "(" + dateString + ") " + task;
  }
}
```

Comment: is that compile? You doesn't return result in `getView` method if `convertedView!=null`

Comment: just a question: your list contains the duplicates or it's only when you show it? @deathember he/she returns return convertView;

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason is you have `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` in `onCreate()` and `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);` in `onResume()`?

I think that `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` in `onCreate()` is enough.

Comment: Oh, it is not displaying because now you don't launch loader in onResume() when you return from NoteEdit activity. I didn't think about it. Thus I think you don't need initLoader() in onCreate(). But anyway you say the problem is still there...

Comment: You also can try to put Debug Break Point somewhere in onLoadFinished() and check whether Cursor has duplicated data or not. Good luck

Comment: My debuger is not working. I received a Cannot connect to Vm socked closed error.I feel so unlucky right now...

Comment: It is not a problem. You can add logging. First, you could log how many items your cursor have and the second you can output every item in the logcat. At least you will know whether you get right data set or not.

Comment: I found something interesting.The logcat show me 181 records while the application display 189. How can I change the onLoadFinished so that my list items are not recorded twice?

Comment: I found out why it was saving twice. It was from another class that I thought is not related to my problem. My mistake , I am blaming the tiredness. Thank you all for help :)